# Metrics for screening stocks for pivot trading

Tags: stocks, trading, volatility, day-trading

I've been looking for tips on screening stocks that are a good fit for pivot trading. I've tried Ameritrade, ShareBuilder, NASDAQ and some other screeners but I don't see a metric for volatility which is the only metric I know about.

What other metrics should I be using to determine candidates while screening?

Update: I was able to find on the NASDAQ screener a place to apply a beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also look for stocks that have significant news flow as this usually increases volatility and offers more trading opportunities.